# set commands for the condition "I'm redirected to another page" (php)

Tags: php, web, url, redirect, alert

I'm using php
I have a process form for a comment page that when you click on submit, you will be redirected to the main page of the website
when I redirected to index.php from my processform.php, I want to see an alert in my index that "Your comment was saved!" (It needs that my index page understand that I'm coming from processform.php)
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use something like sessions.
set session on submit form. and on `index.php` check if session has set with the special key. then show the alert that you want.

- on form submit and success :

```
// Start the session
session_start();
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["processform"] = "Your comment was saved!";
```

- on index.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION["processform"]){
 // do alert
}
```